# Variable Scope in Closure

Tags: javascript

In the following code (from [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://www.manning.com/resig/)), I don't understand why `inner | tooLate` prints out `ronin`. I would've expected `undefined`.

```
var outerValue = "ninja";
var later;

function outerFunction() {
    var innerValue = "samurai";

    function innerFunction(paramValue) {
        console.log("outerValue:",outerValue);
        console.log("innerValue:",innerValue);
        console.log("paramValue:",paramValue);
        console.log("inner | tooLate", tooLate);
    }
    later = innerFunction;
}

console.log("outer | tooLate", tooLate);

var tooLate = "ronin";

outerFunction();
later("warrior");
```

My confusion is how `tooLate` is accessible within `innerFunction`. Isn't `innerFunction`'s scope limited to `outerFunction`?

http://jsfiddle.net/6HuaS/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innerFunction` is under `outerFunction` which is under `window`, therefore `innerFunction` can access all properties and methods of `window`.

In your example, `tooLate` is declared under the `window` scope (global). Since you haven't declare a new `tooLate` in `outerFunction` nor `innerFunction`, it will trace back all the way to `window` to find a declared `tooLate`.

```
var b, val = 0;
function a(){
    b = function (){
        console.log(val);
    }
}
a();
val = 2;
b();  //2
```

```
Scope:

window
├─ a: function
│　└─ b: function      b can access variables in a, b, and all the way to window
└─ val: number         if the variable name hasn't been overridden
```

Comment: Hi +Derek - so a nested function (function within function) has scope limited to (1) parent function's entire scope *and* (2) globals?

Comment: @KevinMeredith - To be short a function can access all variables except the ones in further nested functions/scopes.

Comment: Ah, and I suppose this bullet point (from the book) echoes what you said: `All variables in an outer scope, even those declared after the function declaration,
are included.`

Comment: @KevinMeredith - Yup. Here's a demo to demonstrate that point: http://jsfiddle.net/ybze4/